# Antd TimePicker not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use a timepicker from Antd and for some reason it's not rendering correctly. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-error-191kl?file=/src/App.js). It doesn't look how it is supposed to and when you try to select a time you get a weird bug. I get a similar issue in vs code when I try locally. Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't include the CSS it recommended. https://ant.design/components/time-picker/

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/45fhb?file=/index.js:61-89

Comment: Oh right. I added the css file to my local project, and now it works. But then how come in the code sample on the website it doesn't have the css file, only in the samples on Codesandbox and Codeblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the sample code on the documentation doesn't mention that but if you see the Codesandbox link mentioned in the documentation itself you will find this CSS being included:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Which you need to import too to fix the design issue you are facing.